# how can I make retina simulator in xcode

Tags: macos

I have a mac app

I want to run the app on retina display.

How can I make retina simulator.

I am using xcode 7.1. and mac osx 10.11.3

Comment: launch simulator and press cmd+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the below given software and follow the steps-

1-Install SwitchResX and open it from System Preferences.

2-Go to SwitchResX and select the new custom resolution in the Current Resolution tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale it with the following shortcuts:

```
⌘+1: 100%
⌘+2: 75%
⌘+3: 50%
⌘+4: 33%
⌘+5: 25%
```

Or in iOS Simulator: Window > Scale > ...

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on simulator that you select. If you select iphone 6 simulator then it is by default retina simulator and if you select ipda2 then it is by default non retina simulator. you don't have option to select retina simulator separately.

Simulator comes with real device's functionality. if real device have retina display then it's simulator have also retina display. that's it.

hope this will help :)

Comment: I have non retina mac mini device ,I want to run my mac app on retina display .Then how can I test my mac app on retina disply.

Comment: okay you are talking about mac. i was understood ios. i don't have much idea for osx simulators

Answer (score 0):

- In Xcode, go to the Xcode menu -> Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools.
- A page will open in Safari - Sign in with your Apple Developer Account.
- Download the appropriate version of Graphics Tools.
- Copy them into wherever you want to use them from.
- The tool you're interested in is 'Quartz Debug'.  Load it up.
- Select 'UI Resolution' from the 'Window' menu.  Click 'Enable HiDPI display modes'.
- Log out, and log in again.
- Now if you go to 'System Preferences' you can select 'Retina' modes on your non retina display (but be warned that you won't be able to fit much on your screen when you do!).

Comment: I follow these step but I not seen any retina mode.

Comment: How odd.  What model Mac are you using?  The only one I've tried it on that failed was a Retina Mac with an external display.  On all non-retina machines that I've tried it's worked fine - including on an old G4.

Comment: I am using mac mini (late 2012) with osx 10.11.3.